# Eclipse Read-Only installation setup

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-jdt, multi-user

I need to setup a eclipse installation for a windows network.
My Problem is, that I want to have eclipse to have some plugins installed by default for every user.
I have no idea on how to setup eclipse to support for example java + PHP development by default.
Eclipse is supposed to be installed in a read-only directory, but every user should have it's own preferences.
Any help is very appreciated, since the eclipse documentation discusses this topic very poorly.

Comment: Do you want to let users install more plugins in addition to the default plugins provided by you? Or do you completely decide about the plugins to be used, and only user preferences should be free for configuration by each user? The reason I'm asking this is: shared installs, which have been promoted some time ago, have proven to be quite problematic when it comes to updating. Maybe that's why little has been written about this approach.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann no I don't want to allow that (since sometimes this breaks an installation) and yes shared installs is that thing I was looking for, but I have no Idea on how to set that up. The Updating thingy is not that important because currently everything needs to be updated manually every couple months...

Comment: So if installing / updating after the fact is not important, it seems all you need is one privileged account, which you use for initially installing everything (like you would for a private install), then make it readonly accesible to others and you should be fine. I'm not quite sure, which aspect of this would be a problem for you.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann The Problem is the network e.g. Every time a user loggs in a new local user is created on windows and all appData is reset to the default causing eclipse to lose all of it's installed plugins...

Comment: But if the initial installation is readonly, **that** set of plugins should be available to every user. Only things added on top (incl. user preferences) will be stored in the user's directory (in `.eclipse`). So if you want to preserve preferences accross creation of new temp user accounts, you may have to explicitly handle that directory.

Comment: Perhaps you are saying, that even the plugins which you want to share, are installed only in your temporary user account? In that case the problem would be that you didn't have write access when installing. Is that it?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Yes, thats what I'm saying... That could actually be the case, since I didn't start eclipse as admin (which is required for writing in this directory...) That you so much!

Answer (score 1):

*It is probably something like a system folder.

**First**, you could change the installation in another folder. If you can't or don't want to, you can solve this by:*

Right-clicking on the folder>
Properties>
Uncheck "Read-only"

*Although, you have to make sure its parent folder has to be also unchecked, and its parent, etc...

Of course, **there is a good reason** why Windows made these folders read-only so make sure you know what you are doing.*

Comment: for some reason, my Windows 10 copy turns back on the read-only mode automatically and installation still fails.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Eclipse should be copied to the root directory (ie c:).

**Just create an Eclipse folder (c:\Eclipse) manually**. Then the installation should go through.

This is no problem for you as administrator, the installer has no permission for this, because Windows has taken appropriate security precautions when it comes to the Windows partition.